# Call POST data from one servlet to another server

Tags: java, http, gwt, servlets, http-headers

I am submitting JSON data from my GWT-Client and Passing it to my GWT-Server. And i want to re-submit data to another server and want response from another server to GWT-Client.

I just don't know how can i do this. I tried below code but not working.

My Code is :

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("POST");

    StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.google.com");

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) oracle.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    request.getInputStream();

    OutputStream wr = connection.getOutputStream();

    InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
    int read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    while (read >= 0) {
        wr.write(buffer, 0, read);
        read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    }

    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    BufferedReader in1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in1.readLine()) != null) {
        jb.append(inputLine);
    }
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    // Get the printwriter object from response to write the required json
    // object to the output stream
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    // Assuming your json object is **jsonObject**, perform the following,
    // it will return your json object
    out.print(jb.toString());
    out.flush();
    in1.close();
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: would this be a good candidate for HTML5 web sockets?

Comment: no.. i don't want to use HTML5 web sockets because it will not support IE6 :(

Comment: change job if people force to support IE6. This is inhumane.

Comment: I've had bad experiences with GWT and IE6

Comment: I'd also suggest to consider async response in this case (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085235/servlet-3-async-context-how-to-do-asynchronous-writes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to send the request to the other server before reading the response

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://www.anotherserver.com/");

HttpURLConnection connection = null;
connection = (HttpURLConnection) oracle.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);

OutputStream wr = connection.getOutputStream ();

InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[512]; 
int read = in.read(buffer,0, buffer.length);
while (read >= 0) {
   wr.write(buffer,0, read);
   read = in.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
}

wr.flush ();
wr.close ();


BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        connection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    jb.append(inputLine);
}
```

see also [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: @andih..thanks for answer..but where is String "query" and from where "postParameters" comes???

Comment: `postParameter` was a copy and paste error. I've removed it. `query` is generated from the original post parameters. For simplicity I've created query from only two parameters which are initialized with the parameters from the origianal request. In productive code you would generate the query String using a loop over all parameters found within the parameterMap

Comment: @andih...but i am sending json from client side like this " {temp:'123'} so how can i encode and send to another server??

Comment: I've replaced my copy post parameters by copy the request body. You  should consider setting the correct encoding i.e. the encoding of the original request before you copy the body content to the "other" server.

Comment: @audih..I replaced my code in question..please check it..but still am receiving error "java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://www.google.com"

Comment: @audhi..Hey thanks dude..its working now with my actual server... :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you can use [Apache httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/), it's very simple to implement your requirement, such as :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.anotherserver.com/");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key",
                "value"));
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```